# java: invalid flag: UTF-8 when running Android app in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I initially ran my Android app in IntelliJ, it ran smoothly with no errors. Now when I try to run it (I didn't make any changes), I get one error: java: invalid flag: UTF-8

Any ideas how to fix or bypass this?

EDIT: I was able to solve this by leaving "Additional Command Parameters" blank under Compiler > Java Compiler

Comment: If you fixed your problem, post an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Cashes/Restart  :)

Comment: try to set encoding flag in intellij to default. and rebuild project and invalidate cashes.